# Why is $match not used in the Mongo Aggregation query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

As described in the mongo documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

There is a query for the following SQL query:

```
SELECT cust_id,
       SUM(li.qty) as qty
FROM orders o,
     order_lineitem li
WHERE li.order_id = o.id
GROUP BY cust_id
```

And the equivalent mongo aggregation query is as follows:

```
db.orders.aggregate( [
   { $unwind: "$items" },
   {
     $group: {
        _id: "$cust_id",
        qty: { $sum: "$items.qty" }
     }
   }
] )
```

However, the query is workinf fine as expected. My question, why is there no $match clause for the corresponding WHERE clause in SQL? And how is $unwind compensating the $match clause?

Comment: Your schema has taken care of `WHERE li.order_id = o.id` as now `$items` is a embedded documents in order document. So that relationship is established when you save the order documents with order items. You `$unwind` the `$items` and `$group` to calculate the `$sum` of its fields.

Comment: To add to Veeram's comment; the sql query as presented is misleading, because the WHERE clause should really be an ON clause as part of the join between the two sql tables. Once you realise that there is only a join, and no real WHERE clause, that explains why you don't need an equivalent $match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by @Veeram is correct.  The `where` clause in the SQL is unnecessary because the `items` list is embedded in the orders collection, where in a relational database you would have both an `orders` table and an `orders_lineitem` table (names taken from the description at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/)

Per the example data, you start with documents like this:

```
{
  cust_id: "abc123",
  ord_date: ISODate("2012-11-02T17:04:11.102Z"),
  status: 'A',
  price: 50,
  items: [ { sku: "xxx", qty: 25, price: 1 },
           { sku: "yyy", qty: 25, price: 1 } ]
}
```

When you `$unwind`, the items are unwound but the rest of the data is projected.  If you run a query like

```
db.orders.aggregate([ {"$unwind": "$items"} ])
```

you get the output

```
{
  cust_id: "abc123",
  ord_date: ISODate("2012-11-02T17:04:11.102Z"),
  status: 'A',
  price: 50,
  items: { sku: "xxx", qty: 25, price: 1 }
},
{
  cust_id: "abc123",
  ord_date: ISODate("2012-11-02T17:04:11.102Z"),
  status: 'A',
  price: 50,
  items: { sku: "yyy", qty: 25, price: 1 }
}
```

That has flattened the `items` array, allowing the `$group` to add the `items.qty` field:

```
db.orders.aggregate([ 
    {"$unwind": "$items"},
    {"$group": {
        "_id": "$cust_id",
        "qty": {"$sum": "$items.qty"}
       }
     }])
```

With the output:

```
{ "_id": "abc123",
  "qty": 50
}
```